# Questions about the onDidChangeModelContent event in Monaco

Tags: monaco-editor

The description of changes in onDidChangeModelContent in the monaco document is：

#### Properties

Readonly changes
changes: IModelContentChange[]

[Document link](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.imodelcontentchangedevent.html#changes)

What confuses me is that I only get one changes every time I type.

```
changes: [{…}] // one change
eol: "\n"
isFlush: false
isRedoing: false
isUndoing: false
versionId: 23
```

I want to ask under what circumstances will I get multiple changes. such as:

```
changes: [{…},{…}] // multiple change
eol: "\n"
isFlush: false
isRedoing: false
isUndoing: false
versionId: 23
```

I'm very much obliged to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get multiple changes when you have multiple carets active. By default the editor control allows to set multiple carets in the text (use <kbd>opt</kbd>/<kbd>alt</kbd> and left click to set an additional caret). When you then type a letter, it will be inserted in all places where a caret is, creating so multiple change events for a single action.